# R shiny: dynamic creation of tabular input of different types

Tags: r, dynamic, input, shiny, tabular

I've searched quite a while for this, but I haven't found a solution to my problem. I am building a project management app and I wanted to use shiny because I thought it will be able to make the app more interactive.

So inputs for the app should be done within the app. Inputs will be numeric, text, and choices. For overview, inputs that belong together should be arranged in one line. For example:

resource_1,  name='Confocal Microscope', type='machine', price=1000, price_type='EUR/usage'

I want to arrange each entry in a tabular. Of course the number of entries is variable. Sometimes you might define 5 resources for a project, sometimes 50.

To tackle this problem I create a tabular in shiny with html elements as table entries. However, I need to access these entries dynamically. I thought I could do that by calling the character strings of input IDs of each table entry with the get() function. But that doesn't work.

Now:

- I can create a tabular with different types of input and a variable number of rows.
- I can call each of these inputs by actually calling the input ID (like 'input$element1_1'
- but I can't make a loop to automatically access these input ID's, like with get(): get(paste0('input$element',i,'_',j))

minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui = 
  pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("TEST"),

sidebarPanel(
  helpText("number of resources"),
  numericInput("nres","",3,min=0),
  actionButton('create_res',"create",icon=icon("plus"),width='100%'),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  bsButton('finish_res',"finish",width='100%',style="info"), # check matrix
  width=2
),

mainPanel(    
  uiOutput('matrix_res'),
  p("make an entry in row1 col1 and press finish"),
  br(),
  p("I can extract elements by calling input$element1_1:"),
  textOutput('check1'),
  br(),
  p("but not by searching for the character string with get('element1_1') "),
  textOutput('check2')
)
)

server = 
  function(input,output){

output$matrix_res <- renderTable({

  input$create_res #create button dependency


  Row_entries <- paste("ressource",1:isolate(input$nres)) #kill nres dependency
  Col_entries <- c("text input","number input","selection")

  matrix <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:length(Row_entries)) {
    matrix[i,1] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='text' value=''>") 
    matrix[i,2] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 2, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='number' value=''>")
    matrix[i,3] <- paste0("<div class='form-group shiny-input-container'>
                          <div>
                          <select id='element", i, "_", 3, "' class='form-control'><option value='a' selected>a</option>
                          <option value='b'>b</option></select>
                          <script type='application/json' data-for='element", i, "_", 3, "'>{}</script>
                          </div></div>") 
  }

  colnames(matrix) <- Col_entries

  matrix

  },sanitize.text.function = identity)


output$check1<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(input$element1_1)
})

output$check2<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(input$get('element1_1'))
})
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Run it: you can change the number of rows by using the number input and the create button. You can call the value of row1 column1 by clicking finish.

If you have any idea how to get hold of these inputs please reply. I'm stuck with this shit for already a week...

Answer (score 0):

so I found an unsatisfying answer.
I tried around with get(), eval(), do.call() and the following actually works:

eval(parse(text=character_string))

so you can make character_string <- paste0('input$element',i,'_',j) or something

So, by this you can make a loop to go through all the inputs and create a list for all the inputs. Actually, I was hoping that it's possible to directly save all inputs into a list.

So here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui = 
pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("TEST"),

sidebarPanel(
  helpText("number of rows"),
  numericInput("nres","",3,min=0),
  actionButton('create_res',"create",icon=icon("plus"),width='100%'),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  helpText("show me value in row 1 column 1"),
  actionButton('finish_res',"show",icon=icon("check"),width='100%'),
  width=2
),

mainPanel(    
  uiOutput('matrix_res'),
  p("just by actually writing 'input$element1_1'"),
  textOutput('check1'),
  br(),
  p("with get(character_string)"),
  textOutput('check2'),
  br(),
  p('with eval(parse(text=character_string)):'),
  textOutput('check3'),
  br(),
  p('with do.call("print", list(as.name(character_string)))'),
  textOutput('check4')
)
)

server = 
function(input,output){

output$matrix_res <- renderTable({

  input$create_res #create button dependency


  Row_entries <- paste("ressource",1:isolate(input$nres)) #kill nres dependency
  Col_entries <- c("text input","number input","selection")

  matrix <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:length(Row_entries)) {
    matrix[i,1] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='text' value=''>") 
    matrix[i,2] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 2, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='number' value=''>")
    matrix[i,3] <- paste0("<div class='form-group shiny-input-container'>
                          <div>
                          <select id='element", i, "_", 3, "' class='form-control'><option value='a' selected>a</option>
                          <option value='b'>b</option></select>
                          <script type='application/json' data-for='element", i, "_", 3, "'>{}</script>
                          </div></div>") 
  }

  colnames(matrix) <- Col_entries

  matrix

  },sanitize.text.function = identity)


output$check1<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(input$element1_1)
})

output$check2<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(get(paste0('input$element',1,'_',1)))
})

output$check3<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(eval(parse(text=paste0('input$element',1,'_',1))))
})

output$check4<-renderText({
  input$finish_res
  isolate(do.call("print",   list(as.name(paste0('input$element',1,'_',1)))))
})

 }

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a way of getting what I wanted.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, because it's just too complicated for a simple task like that.

Note that the inputs are saved if you decide to add more rows.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- 
pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Dynamic table for Input of different types"),

sidebarPanel(
  helpText("number of rows"),
  numericInput("nres","",3,min=0),
  actionButton('create_res',"create",icon=icon("plus"),width='100%'),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  helpText("read input you entered"),
  actionButton('finish_res',"finish",icon=icon("check"),width='100%'),
  width=2
),

mainPanel(  
  h3("input table"),
  uiOutput('matrix_res'),
  h3("output table"),
  tableOutput('check_table'),
  br()

)
)

server <- 
function(input,output){


# input table
# table with different types of input
# row number can be changed with number input
# changes are applied after pressing create button
output$matrix_res <- renderTable({

  input$create_res # dependency


  Col_entries <- c("text input","number input","selection")

  matrix <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:isolate(input$nres)) {
    matrix[i,1] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='text' value='",input[[paste0("element", i, "_", 1)]],"'>") 
    matrix[i,2] <- paste0("<input id='element", i, "_", 2, "' class='shiny-bound-input span6' type='number' value='",input[[paste0("element", i, "_", 2)]],"'>")
    matrix[i,3] <- paste0("<div class='form-group shiny-input-container'><div>
                          <select id='element", i, "_", 3, "' class='form-control'>
                          <option value='a'>a</option>
                          <option value='b'>b</option>
                          </div></div>") 
  }

  colnames(matrix) <- Col_entries

  matrix


  },sanitize.text.function = identity)




# change row number for output table
# only if new input table is created with create button
row_number<-reactive({
  input$create_res # dependency
  isolate(input$nres) 
})




# output table
# object created when clicking on finish button
# only dependent on finish button
output_table<-reactive({

  input$finish_res # dependency

  Col_entries <- c("text input","number input","selection")

  matrix <- data.frame()

  isolate(
    for (i in 1:isolate(row_number())) {
      matrix[i,1] <- input[[paste0('element',i,'_',1)]]
      matrix[i,2] <- input[[paste0('element',i,'_',2)]]
      matrix[i,3] <- input[[paste0('element',i,'_',3)]]
    }
  )
  colnames(matrix) <- Col_entries

  matrix

})


# show output table
output$check_table<-renderTable({
  if(input$finish_res == 0) return() #hide it on start
  output_table()
})

}


runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```